# Carregar arquivo javascript somente em uma página

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Galera, to apanhando com uma coisa, imagino que deveria ser simples, porém estou o dia todo movendo arquivos pra cima e pra baixo e não resolvo kkkkkkk

Seguinte, tenho um sistema dentro de um template Gentelella, e como padrão, ele carrega diversos arquivos javascript no final da página.

Meu código, por sempre repetir o início e fim, tenho uma página header.php e uma footer.php. Nessa footer tem todas as inclusões de bibliotecas ficando assim:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="../vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
<script src="../vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap-datetimepicker -->    
<!-- bootstrap-wysiwyg -->
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap-wysiwyg/js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/jquery.hotkeys/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.js"></script>
<!-- Summernote Text Editor -->
<script src="../vendors/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>

<script src="../vendors/dist/lang/summernote-pt-BR.js"></script>    
<!-- jQuery Tags Input -->
<script src="../vendors/jquery.tagsinput/src/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
<!-- Switchery -->
<script src="../vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="../vendors/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>   
<!-- Autosize -->
<script src="../vendors/autosize/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery autocomplete -->
<script src="../vendors/devbridge-autocomplete/dist/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>    
<!-- starrr -->
<script src="../vendors/starrr/dist/starrr.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Ion.RangeSlider -->
<script src="../vendors/ion.rangeSlider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Colorpicker -->
<script src="../vendors/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery.inputmask -->
<script src="../vendors/jquery.inputmask/dist/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob -->
<script src="../vendors/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Carrega clientes na OS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clientes.js"></script>
```

Bom o que acontece. Estou incluindo na última linha o arquivo clientes.js, que faz uma requisição no BD com uma lista de clientes, e nela utilizo Jquery e Jquery UI.
Ai que começa a bagunça, quando coloco o arquivo jquery-ui no meu footer, dependendo da posição, ou para de funcionar outros recursos do template, ou para meu código. Ao que parece acaba complicando por causa do autocomplete que já está invocado nesse footer.

A "gambiarra" que pensei em fazer é, tentar carregar o arquivo jquery-ui.js apenas na página em que preciso dela. Porém não imagino como fazer isso. A solução "fácil" seria tirar o header e footer desta página e colocar tudo no arquivo da página, mas quero evitar isso, pois se mudo qualquer coisa nos menus (que ainda está em desenvolvimento) tenho que ir também nessa página e alterar também.

Enfim, qualquer dica aí me ajuda galera. Forte abraço e a todos um ótimo fim de semana.

Comment: Os scrips aparecem em todas as paginas?

Comment: Achei que não iria funcionar, mas deu certo sim, obrigado cara. Na verdade, era um complemento renderitem do meu código que causava erro, como só carrega agora o script na página que eu preciso, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma condição para seus scripts para que sejam executados apenas em uma url especifica.

```
if (window.location.href == "https://seusite.com") { //se a pagina corresponder, executar a função
   //sua função aqui 
}
```